# Changing number of divs in row and divs are showing instead of display is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two 'options' divs, first block is main divs and they are showed when page is loaded, and also I have sub divs that need to be hidden on page load, I created a function that hide them but I still can see them on page for about a second and than they are hidden, how to solve this so I dont see them at all when page load. And also, how to create so in row I have 4 divs, because I have 8 main divs so I want to have 4 in row.

Example code with HTML and JavaScript that hide sub divs.

CSS And function that hides sub divs, I said it, its work fine and function hide them on page load but I can see them for about a second when page is loaded.

```js
const subDivs = ["aH-summerCamps", "aH-trekking", "bP-longDistanceHiking", "bP-thruHiking", "c-oceanCruising", "c-riverCruising", "e-recreationsEvent", "e-sportsEvents", "pH-escortedTours", "pH-independentTours", "s-photographicSafari", "s-cyclingSafari", "sAs-backcountrySkiing", "v-conservationAndEnvironment", "sAs-downhillSkiing", "v-childcare"]
  .map(id => document.getElementById(id));

function hideAllSubDivs(id) {
  for (const div of subDivs) div.hidden = !(div.id === id);
}

window.onload = function() {
  hideAllSubDivs(subDivs);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 380px;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 180px 180px 180px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.a {
  background: #0d9;
}

.b {
  background: #d90;
}

.c {
  background: #9d0;
}

.d {
  background: #90d;
}

.e {
  background: #d09;
}

.f {
  background: #09d;
}

.g {
  background: #09d;
}

.h {
  background: #09d;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <!--main divs-->
  <div style="background-color: #4cc9f0" class="item a" id="adventureHolidays">
    <p>Adventure Holidays</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4895ef" class="item b" id="backpacking">
    <p>Backpacking</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4361ee" class="item c" id="cruiseHolidays">
    <p>Cruise Holidays</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4361ee" class="item d" id="eventTravel">
    <p>Event Travel</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #3a0ca3" class="item e" id="packageHoliday">
    <p>Package Holiday</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #480ca8" class="item f" id="safari">
    <p>Safari</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #560bad" class="item g" id="skiingAndSnowboarding">
    <p>Skiing and Snowboarding</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #7209b7" class="item h" id="volunteering">
    <p>Volunteering</p>
  </div>

  <!--end on main divs-->

  <!--sub divs this is hidden on page load but I can see them for about a second on page load and then dissaper-->

  <div style="background-color: #4cc9f0" class="column" id="aH-summerCamps">
    <p>Summer camps</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4895ef" class="column" id="aH-trekking">
    <p>Trekking</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4361ee" class="column" id="bP-longDistanceHiking">
    <p>Long Distance Hiking</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4361ee" class="column" id="bP-thruHiking">
    <p>Thru Hiking</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #3a0ca3" class="column" id="c-oceanCruising">
    <p>Ocean Cruising</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #480ca8" class="column" id="c-riverCruising">
    <p>River Cruising</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #560bad" class="column" id="e-recreationsEvent">
    <p>Recreations Events</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #7209b7" class="column" id="e-sportsEvents">
    <p>Sports events</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4cc9f0" class="column" id="pH-escortedTours">
    <p>Escorted Tours</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4895ef" class="column" id="pH-independentTours">
    <p>Independent Tours</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4361ee" class="column" id="s-photographicSafari">
    <p>Photographic Safari</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4895ef" class="column" id="s-cyclingSafari">
    <p>Cycling Safari</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #3a0ca3" class="column" id="sAs-backcountrySkiing">
    <p>Backcountry skiing</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #560bad" class="column" id="sAs-downhillSkiing">
    <p>Downhill skiing</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4361ee" class="column" id="v-childcare">
    <p>Childcare</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4895ef" class="column" id="v-conservationAndEnvironment">
    <p>Conservation And Environment
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Add class for sub divs and you can get them easier and write `display: none` in CSS.

Comment: I know, but I have function for example when user click on `adventureHolidays` I need to show him `aH-summerCamps` and `aH-trekking` so that is the reason why I want that on this way.

Comment: Just use javascript to set style `display: unset;` or something etc.